# Increment json property in json column Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a posts and reviews on these posts. I need increment properties in json column. How I can do it?

```
// For example:
// posts-table
// Json-Column: "reviews"
// {"reviews_count": 1}

// Does not work
$review->post->increment('reviews->reviews_count');
$review_good->post->increment('reviews->reviews_good_count');
```

Comment: $review->post['reviews->reviews_count'] += 1;
$review->post->save(); how about this ?

Comment: also check https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/ the last part maybe you can do some kind of Accessor to do this $review->post->reviews_count->increment();